# Closed a modal at the end of the video

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, video, modal-dialog

I have a video in a modal boostraps. I can not figure out how to do it, to close the modal at the end of the video.

```
<section class="video">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg video__btnModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video__btnModal">VIDEO</button>
  <div id="video__btnModal" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <video controls id="video1" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin:0 auto; frameborder:0;">
            <source src="./assets/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="./assets/video/video.mov" type="video/mov">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        // What you want to do after the event
    }
</script>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#video1").on("ended", function() {
   //TO DO: Your code goes here...
      alert("Video Finished");
});
```

to hide modal you need to call

```
$('#video__btnModal').modal('hide');// hides the modal 

$('#video__btnModal').modal('toggle');// toggles between hide and show
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help